# Android studio create/generate icons for all android version types

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, capacitor, android-icons

I have a mobile app project that's working fine but recently notified that icons are showing as a old default android robot icon for older android devices. I've only used the android studio built in `image asset` manager for my icons, as well as [cordova-res](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/splash-screens-and-icons). How would I come about to make sure I provide for all android version types?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this link to generate all Android icons for your project
[Android asset studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html)

so you will end with **6** different icons in your res folder

1. mipmap-ldpi
2. mipmap-mdpi
3. mipmap-hdpi
4. mipmap-xhdpi
5. mipmap-xxhdpi
6. mipmap-xxxhdpi

[more details about icons in Google developer website](https://developer.android.com/distribute/google-play/resources/icon-design-specifications)

Apart of that you will need a icon for the Google Play store in 512x512px size